Architecture design for a bus ticketing system (mobile app)
I'm new to software engineering and designing an architecture for a bus ticketing system for my assignment, which provides the following functions for customers:

Book tickets
Check schedule
Check real-time bus location
Get notifications when the bus schedule is delayed or canceled

I'm assuming that the system should have these 2 quality attributes:

Reliability (any changes in information, such as schedule and bus location, should be reflected immediately in the app)
Maintainability (for future improvements and maintenance)

However, I found that there are not many architecture patterns to achieve reliability.

Here's my current solution. Since it is a mobile app, I think a client-server architecture (maybe 2-tiers or 3-tiers) is suitable to achieve maintainability. However, for reliability, I have these few options:
Broker (Event-driven) Architecture
This is to broadcast changes to components in the system to react to changes. I don't think this is practical because most examples I have seen are for systems that need a fast response (and my lecturer does not seem to agree with this idea either).
Observer Architecture
Similar to what Broker does, but the observers only monitor selected observees. I'm still not sure how Observer differs from Broker.
Microservice Architecture
This is so far my top choice because it can have redundant components to handle the work, but from most information I have seen, it is mainly for systems with a lot of APIs, not for monolithic systems.
What do you think? Are there any related articles I can refer to?
